# A $3\times3$ matrix is multiplied by an unknown $3\times1$ matrix and if the result is $\mathbf{0}$ how do I compute the unknown matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

So my question is basically how to find the numerical values of $x_1$ $x_2$ and $x_3$ in the following equation.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -3 \\
-2 & 2 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \mathbf{0}
$$

I can do that in basic and easy to see matrices but I couldn't be able to find the solution for this matrix.

Comment: It's a system of three equations with three unknowns. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Should I take the RREF of the first matrix?

Comment: Yes and you should investigate how this notation is exactly the same as the one you're accustomed to.

Comment: So I guess I got the answer as multiples of $$\begin{bmatrix} -5/3 \\ -2/3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So any multiple of this matrix is an answer for this equation right?

Comment: @Mkaansa Yes, that is correct

Comment: The result is not a scalar $0$ but instead a vector with three components, each $0$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for their help :)

Comment: @Mkaansa I would also add that scalar multiples of a vector form a line through the origin. This line will itself be a vector space and is sometimes called a solution space, since it contains the solutions. These spaces can be more complicated if there are less equations than unknowns but the same idea holds, all solutions will form their own vector space. All of this is true because of the $0$ vector on the right hand side so that's why you're studying this form.

Comment: Just a remark, it is usually called an unknown vector, not an unknown matrix.